# How does Python know that all of these variants of π are the same variable name?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

There are (at least) 3 variants of the greek letter pi in the Unicode standard with different code points. But if I assign any one of them as an identifier to a Python object, I can use any of the others as well:

```
In [1]: π = 3.14
In [2]: print(π)  # \u03c0
3.14

In [3]: print()  # \U0001d6d1
3.14

In [4]: print()  # \U0001d70b
3.14
```

How does Python know that these names are the same?

Comment: No, you need to assign and it's the same for many similar characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the original PEP3131 [explained](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/):

> All identifiers are converted into the normal form NFKC while parsing; comparison of identifiers is based on NFKC.

This is also covered in the [Identifiers and Keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html?highlight=nfkc#identifiers) section of the docs.

And so:

```
In [58]: pis = ["\u03c0", "\U0001d6d1", "\U0001d70b"]

In [59]: pis
Out[59]: ['π', '', '']

In [60]: [ord(pi) for pi in pis]
Out[60]: [960, 120529, 120587]

In [61]: import unicodedata

In [62]: [unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', pi) for pi in pis]
Out[62]: ['π', 'π', 'π']

In [63]: [ord(unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', pi)) for pi in pis]
Out[63]: [960, 960, 960]
```